# How can I Reverse Engineer Default Column Values that use scalar functions with EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ef-core-3.0

I'm looking at upgrading our Storage Layer form Linq To Sql to EF Core 3.

I can reverse engineer the model from the database using the scaffolding command and it correctly creates FK fields who's default value is looked up using a Scalar Function called `dbo.DefaultSystem()`

But then I can't use EF Core to create a database from scratch because it can't scaffold programmability.

Is there, like, some kind of pre-create hook I can grab? Or better yet, a way to trigger code *after* the `Systems` table has been created.

Once `Systems` has been created I can just execute some SQL to create the `DefaultSystem` function.

I have to assume that there's logic in EF Core that knows it has to create the Systems table before it creates all the tables who have foreign keys pointing at it?

***Update for comment from JDWeng***

*"You [create? - ed] the database first. What is your connection string? Are you connecting to a server (the server attached to an MDF file) or a LocalDb which is an MDF file?"*

Source Connection String for Reverse Engineering:

`@"Server=SQLDEV01\2008R2;Database=Database_Version_88;Trusted_Connection=True;"`

Destination Connection String to test `db.EnsureDeleted();db.EnsureCreated();`

`@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=LocalDevTest_Version_88;Trusted_Connection=True;"`

So, the source database is hosted on a Windows Server running Sql Server 2008R2. This is our restricted schema design server which holds the design for our database. We create schema shapshots and upgrade scripts between the multiple database versions. This server is considered design gospel.

The target database is a `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` which is created via EnsureCreated() from the DbContext generated by the Scaffold binaries.
I don't know much about the internals of this but according to your comment I'm just creating and connecting directly to an `mdf` file.

If there's nothing automatic to do this, I guess I'll have to create the database first with the System Of Record tables pre-created and configured and seeded.

Comment: You the database first.  What is your connection string?  Are you connecting to a server (the server atttached to an MDF file) or a LocalDb which is an MDF file?

Comment: @jdweng Question updated with answers to your questions